# Is it possible to get data(search term) from the google search widget

Tags: android, google-search

I might sound stupid ,but is there any possible way to get the search term which user is typing or has typed in google search widget. and if yes how can i get it .
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple answer, no. Unless, maybe, if you are the launcher. But that just sounds hacky

Comment: @JordyLangen thanks for the reply ! so it means there is no work around.?